# What is the logic behind, what onPressed takes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    void moveToReg()
    {
      //it is a function
    }

  onPressed: moveToReg  //It works 
  onPressed: moveToReg(); //It gives an error
```

> I am an absolute beginner and I want to ask why onPressed takes function without Parentheses ?

Comment: cos it has its own parenthesis already, as you defined on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onPressed take function without parenthesis passes a reference (a pointer) to the function 
`moveToreg` to the `onPressed` parameter and just because  the parameters of the callback expected by `onPressed` and `moveToreg` are compatible.

Comment: It's unclear due to grammatical errors, can you please make it more clear ?                    Thank You for helping.

Comment: the `moveToreg` function without parentheses passes a reference (a pointer) to the `moveToreg` function to `onPressed`. the parameters of the callback expected by `onPressed` and `moveToreg` are compatible.